# Delphi - execute functions and procedures from external file

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is it possible to read and execute procedure or function from a text file?

Comment: You could try [DWScript](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using a Delphi scripting engine like [`Pascal Script`](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx) or [`dwscript`](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/).

Comment: + 1 for Pascal Script, but i dont know how to use dwscript.

Comment: @Robrok for DWS you can check the documentation http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/wiki/FirstSteps

Answer (score 5):

yes, you can execute procedures, functions, macros, scripts, reports, custom forms and other  by using [JVCL Interpreter](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/JvInterpreter.htm)

Comment: on my machine I haven't encountered this issue... I've installed the entire JEDI JCL/JVCL suite and the install compiles all the sources from the project.

Comment: Please give a link to the file!

Comment: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/Main_Page .Also, there are tutorials and videos on the internet on how to install it.

Comment: Antoher third component that isn`t working on Windows XP from Russia and Delphi7. The error : "The program has encountered a problem sorry closin`" :(

Comment: you can look in the log files to see what happened. also, there is a FAQ section on the site.

Comment: @Warren - yes, I know. That was the reason for posting the answer.